# How to write a C++ program that simulates the rolling of two dice

Tags: c++

I am new at this and I don't even know really know what I am doing yet. But I have an assignment to create a program that simulates the rolling of two dice. The program should call rand to roll the first dice, and should call rand again to roll the second dice.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
//rolling two dice 40000 times
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    int face1=0,  face2=0, sum=0, roll=40000;//declaring variables and total rolls

    srand (time(NULL));//setting random number

    while (roll>0){


        face1 =rand()% 6 + 1;
        cout<<"Your first roll is " <<face1<< endl;
        face2 =rand()% 6 + 1;
        cout<<"You second roll is" <<face2<< endl;

    
    sum = face1+face2;//sum of rolls
    cout <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't really know if it's even right but I am more confused with the last part of the question which is:

Use a single-subscripted array to tally the numbers of times each sum appears. Print the results in a tabular format. Also, determine if the totals are reasonable, ( i.e, there are six ways to roll a 7), so approximately 1/6 of all the rolls should be a 7.

How do I do that?

Comment: The last part is just asking you to print all the sums (2 to 12) in a table with a count for how many times each sum occurred.

Comment: Note that there's no condition to break from the `while` loop. You'd be stuck in there forever. Maybe you wanted to include a counter to count the number of times you have rolled the dice, the upper limit of the counter should be the maximum numbers or rolls allowed (i.e., 40000).

Comment: Have you studied arrays? Think about what `totals[sum]++` would do if totals was an `int totals[13]`

Comment: You might also (C++11 and later) consider using facilities from the standard header `<random>` to generate your values.   Using `srand()` and `rand()` in C++ is really the poor-man's solution (documented examples readily available due to history in the C library, poor randomness, etc).   Consider the example given at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Which part of the last part is confusing you? The part that strikes me as oddest is *"Use a single-subscripted array"*, but that just means use an array that will be accessed via `array[sum]`, not via `array[face1][face2]`. In any event, what you call "the last part" is actually at least three steps, and you should focus on only one, specific step for a question here.

Answer (score 4):

First we need to fix a major problem in your code. You have an endless loop, because you never decrement the vaiable roll.

So, you need to change the corresponding statement to: `while (roll-- > 0) {`.

Then, you should count the numbers of different sums. Possible outcomes of sums are values between 2 and 12.

So, we need an array to store the count of the sums. Normally only 11 elements would be needed. But, for convenience, we use 13 elements, so that we can directly use the sum as an index into the array. Please remember: Array indices start with 0 in C++.

Example:

```
int sumCounter[13]{};

// Roll your dices

// Then count
++sumCounter[sum];
```

The {} will initialize all values of the array to 0.

Let us do this first.

Then next, we need to check the probability for a sum. Overall you can have 6 * 6 = 36 possible results with 2 dices. We are talking about ordred pairs here. To calculate the theoretical probabilities, we will count again sums for all possible outcomes.

This can be done like this:

```
    int potentialSumCounter[13]{};
    for (int d1 = 1; d1 <= 6; ++d1)
        for (int d2 = 1; d2 <= 6; ++d2)
            ++potentialSumCounter[d1 + d2];

    std::cout << "\n\nTheroretical count of sums:\n";
    for (int k = 2; k <= 12; ++k) {
        std::cout << "Sum: " << k << "\tCount: " << potentialSumCounter[k] << '\n';
    }
```

Then, we multiply the this theoretical value with the number of experiments and calculate the delta between therotical and actual in percent.

Result could look like this:

```
//rolling two dice 40000 times
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

constexpr int NumberOfTests = 40000;

int main()
{
    int face1 = 0, face2 = 0, sum = 0, roll = NumberOfTests;//declaring variables and total rolls
    srand(time(NULL));//setting random number

    int sumCounter[13]{};

    while (roll-- > 0) {


        face1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        //cout << "Your first roll is " << face1 << endl;
        face2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        //cout << "You second roll is" << face2 << endl;


        sum = face1 + face2;//sum of rolls
        ++sumCounter[sum];
        //cout << endl;
    }
    // Show result of rolling dices. Show number of different sums
    std::cout << "\n\nResult of experiment. Count of sums:\n";
    for (int k = 2; k <= 12; ++k) {
        std::cout << "Sum: " << k << "\tCount: " << sumCounter[k] << '\n';
    }
    // Get theroretical values
    int potentialSumCounter[13]{};
    for (int d1 = 1; d1 <= 6; ++d1)
        for (int d2 = 1; d2 <= 6; ++d2)
            ++potentialSumCounter[d1 + d2];

    std::cout << "\n\nTheroretical count of sums:\n";
    for (int k = 2; k <= 12; ++k) {
        double theroretical = 1.0*potentialSumCounter[k] * NumberOfTests / 36;
        int deltaToExperimental = std::abs(potentialSumCounter[k] - theroretical);
        double delta = (1.0*deltaToExperimental / sumCounter[k])*100;
        std::cout << "Sum: " << k << "\tCount: " << sumCounter[k]
            << "\tTheoretical: " << theroretical << "\tAccuracy: " << delta << "%\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One possible outcome:

```
Theroretical count of sums:
Sum: 2  Count: 1129     Theoretical: 1111.11    Accuracy: 98.3171%
Sum: 3  Count: 2286     Theoretical: 2222.22    Accuracy: 97.1129%
Sum: 4  Count: 3387     Theoretical: 3333.33    Accuracy: 98.3171%
Sum: 5  Count: 4530     Theoretical: 4444.44    Accuracy: 98.0132%
Sum: 6  Count: 5539     Theoretical: 5555.56    Accuracy: 100.199%
Sum: 7  Count: 6650     Theoretical: 6666.67    Accuracy: 100.15%
Sum: 8  Count: 5562     Theoretical: 5555.56    Accuracy: 99.7843%
Sum: 9  Count: 4353     Theoretical: 4444.44    Accuracy: 101.999%
Sum: 10 Count: 3275     Theoretical: 3333.33    Accuracy: 101.679%
Sum: 11 Count: 2172     Theoretical: 2222.22    Accuracy: 102.21%
Sum: 12 Count: 1117     Theoretical: 1111.11    Accuracy: 99.3733%
```